# In Visual Studio Code, how to set maximum wrap height?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to prevent really long lines of code from wrapping too high? For example, if a really long line of code were to default wrap to 6 rows high, I would like to truncate it to 3 lines and maybe have a "..." at the end. Is that a feature in VSCode?